# How to read data from IndexedDB with a nested Cursor?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, indexeddb

I'm trying to read data from two different object stores from a IndexedDB. I'm using "nested" Cursors. But it's not working as I'm excepting. It works when I'm reading it separately.

For first student it passes one time through inner cursor, for the second student two times and so on.

I must use IndexedDB with EcmaScript6.

Here is my code:

```
function listMarkByStudents(event){

    let transaction = db.transaction(["students", "marks"], "readonly");
    let storeStudents = transaction.objectStore("students");
    let storeMarks = transaction.objectStore("marks");

    let indexStudents = storeStudents.index('sName');
    let indexMarks = storeMarks.index('idStudent')

    let output = '';

    indexStudents.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event){
        let cursorStudents = event.target.result;
        if(cursorStudents){
            output += "<tr>";
            output += "<td>"+cursorStudents.value.id+"</td>";
            output += "<td>"+cursorStudents.value.sName+"</td>";
            output += "<td>"+cursorStudents.value.email+"</td>";
            output += "</tr>";

            indexMarks.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event){
                let cursorMarks = event.target.result;
                if (cursorMarks){
                    output += "<tr>";
                    output += "<td>"+cursorMarks.value.markValue+"</td>";
                    output += "<td>"+cursorMarks.value.idStudent+"</td>";
                    output += "<td>"+cursorMarks.value.idSubject+"</td>";
                    output += "</tr>";

                    cursorMarks.continue();
                }
            }
            cursorStudents.continue();
        }       
        document.getElementById('StudentsMarkList').innerHTML = output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to solving your problem, but an important question given modern JS: why are you using string concatenation instead of building normal DOM nodes use `document.createElement` and `element.appendChild` etc?

Comment: this code will not work, you need to re-execute the query to get the nested cursor right along with the nested cursor, however i would give up on this approach entirely and just use two cursors where there is no nesting